# Why when I tried to use res.clearCookie to clear the token from the cookie, but it didn't work

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

I used Express.js and tried to clear the Cookies when logging out. But the clearCookie seems doesn't work, the response can be successfully sent, just the token in the cookies was not removed. I had to clear the cookie on front end, which doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.

Besides, I tried to use the useNavigation in the react-router-dom, but it cannot redirect, and I had to use window.location.replace('/login') to redirect.

I have a question about this, if I can use window.location.replace to redirect, why should I use the hook useNavigation, and why it doesn't work here?

Backend controller:

```js
export const logout = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.clearCookie('token');
        return res.json({ ok: true });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Frontend React logout Handler:

```js
const logoutHandler = async () => {
   dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
   window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
   // I don't know why the backend didn't remove the token from the cookie
   // so I remove it manually
   Cookies.remove('token');
   try {
       const data = await logoutApi();
   if (data.ok) {
           toast.success('User successfully Logged out.');
   } else {
       toast.error('Error happened while sending logout request.');
   }} catch (err) {
       toast.error(err);
   }
        window.location.replace('/login');
        // why useNavigate doesn't work either? I tried to use 
    // navigate('/login', { replace: true });
    };
```

Comment: You didn't show how you send the request, but I guess that you use axios or something and you don't save cookies

Comment: @Konrad Thank you, you are right! I found I missed adding withCredential config when sending the axio request.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with these solutions

once verify what name you have given to your token,

1. cookies. Set('testtoken', {expires: Date.now()});
2. cookies. Set('testtoken', {maxAge: 0});
3. res.setHeader('your_cookie_name', 'mycookie=; max-age=0');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).